# I get " 'Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:2222 " when I try to start my honeypot

Tags: security

I'm trying to run my kippo honeypot but I get this error :
An error has occurred: 'Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:2222: [Errno 98] Address already in use.'uldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:2222: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

Answer (score 1):

That generally means some process is already listening on the port, in this case 2222. Try `sudo netstat -pant | grep 2222` to see if that's the case. Then you might kill that process.

Comment: Yes ,fixed that issue already